# Optimize svg filter turbulence to get better performance

Tags: svg, css-animations, svg-animate, svg-filters, css-filters

I'm using a svg turbulence filter to create a water effect but it is lagging on low-end and mid-end computers so I was wondering if there was any way to optimize the animation or if there were any workarounds to get the same result...

I've heard about requestAnimationFrame but as I am using ReactJS, I didn't figured out how I could use it and if it would solve any performance issues...

Here's my code :

```html
<svg>
            <filter
              id="turbulence"
              x="0"
              y="0"
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              colorInterpolationFilters="sRGB"
            >
              <feTurbulence
                id="sea-filter"
                numOctaves="2"
                seed="4"
                baseFrequency="0.02 0.05"
              ></feTurbulence>
              <feDisplacementMap
                scale="25"
                numOctaves="3"
                in2="turbulence"
                in="SourceGraphic"
              ></feDisplacementMap>
            </filter>
            <animate
              xlinkHref="#sea-filter"
              attributeName="baseFrequency"
              dur="120s"
              keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
              values="0.02 0.06;0.04 0.08;0.02 0.06"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
</svg>
<div className={styles.sea} style={{ background: `url(${sea})` }}></div>
```

How I apply it in CSS :

```css
.sea {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../../../assets/images/Hero/Sea/sea.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  filter: url("#turbulence");
  transform: scale(1.5);
  animation: floating 60s ease forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1.5) rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(10%) scale(1.5) rotate(2.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1.5) rotate(0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-10%) scale(1.5) rotate(-2.5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1.5) rotate(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Animating baseFrequency can be performance intensive. When I need to animate turbulence, I add a feColorMatrix/hueRotate animation which seems to be better optimized in browsers.

```
    <feColorMatrix in="cloudbase" type="hueRotate" values="0" result="cloud">
    <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </feColorMatrix>
```

Full example at https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/AZqQqB

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works on Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari... Do you have any idea ? I think safari needs an xlinkHref attribute on the animation to work but I don't know what to put inside ?

Comment: Safari is very unforgiving of mistakes in your syntax. For example, I see in your filter that you have " in='turbulence' " but you don't have a " result='turbulence' " earlier in your filter, so Safari will throw out the whole filter when that happens. If you can post your full opdated code I can try to debug. (Also Safari doesn't support certain things in a CSS filter that references an SVG Filter, but this has been improving over time)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's still very laggy on low-end computers... Do you think making the same effect with Three.js may be more optimized ? (I'm trying to make a water movement effect) I've never used Three.js but it relays on different ressources no ?

Comment: I think it also lags because I have to apply the filter on fullscreen...

Comment: three.js uses WebGl - it might be higher performance - but you can never tell with low end phones with crappy GPU's. Is it any better if you get rid of all the transforms?

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to remove them but there were no change performance wise... I'll try Three ^^

Comment: @LouisLecouturier Three.js is an overkill for such 2d effects, why not use Pixi.js instead?